# Facebook message to page

Tags: facebook, api, message

Is there a way how I can send regular message to facebook page?

I got this:

https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api

but it is unofficial.

When I've tried to send several messages sending account was blocked.
I have not found any info about limits or anything else connected to sending messages to Facebook pages.

In official Facebook documentation regarding messaging API there is nothing about sending message to Page. As bot is acting as Facebook Page itself I suppose it can't send message to another Facebook Page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to send user to page messages, you can only send messages from page to user. And only if the receiver started the conversation first.

Don´t use unofficial ways, they are not allowed.